# Check multiple subdirectories and delete if file exists

Tags: powershell

Long story short, I have over 180K files that I need to delete. I have all of the file names that need to be deleted in a TXT file, however the files that need deleting are scattered in over 400 folders within this one directory.

I'm attempting to design a script that reads a .TXT file, checks if the file exists in any of the sub directories and deletes if found.

I'm quite knew to PowerShell / Object-oriented scripts so need some assistance.

```
$WorkingDir = 'D:\TEST\'
$txtFile = Get-Content "D:\TEST\Files.txt"

#foreach file in the .TXT
foreach ($file in $txtFile){
    # foreach file in the folders
    foreach($dir in (Get-ChildItem $WorkingDir -Recurse)){
        # if the file name is in directory listed, then delete?
            If (Test-Path $file){
                Remove-Item $file
                  }
             }
      }
```

Example of data in TXT file:

```
215865.wav
215864.wav
215875.wav
215887.wav
215885.wav
215884.wav
215902.wav
215906.wav
```

Attempted to run script above on some test data so it didn't have to scan through hundreds of folders...runs successfully but nothing gets deleted.

Comment: Can you confirm that the code is complete and that it functions correctly? If so, I recommend that you [edit] to add a summary of the testing (ideally as reproducible unit-test code).  If it's not working, it isn't ready for review (see [help/on-topic]) and the question may be deleted.

Comment: Okay, I will read the help center. Thanks @Toby

Comment: Editing posts to include suggestions that are given in answers creates an issue where the answers appear to not make sense. We call this ["answer invalidation"](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1763/for-an-iterative-review-is-it-okay-to-edit-my-own-question-to-include-revised-c). Your edits have been rolled back, and the answer now makes more sense. Unfortunately your question was off-topic to start with. Now that you have working code, though, you may want to post a follow up question. See the same link above for how to do that.

Answer (score 2):

Your approach is very inefficient

- the array `$txtfile` is already in memory
- iterating it and per entry searching recursivly the directories (the var $dir in fact also includes files) creates a lot of unneccessary overhead.

```
$WorkingDir = 'D:\TEST\'
$txtFile = Get-Content "D:\TEST\Files.txt"

Get-ChildItem $WorkingDir -Recurse|ForEach-Object{
    If ($txtFile -contains $_.Name){
        Remove-Item $_.FullName -WhatIf
    }
}
```

If the output looks OK, remove the trailing `-WhatIf`